# issue installing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've checked many other posts but I can't seem to find a solution, I get the same error each time I try to install this gem. I've tried reinstalling and even changing ruby versions (I tried my original 25 install then the latest 26 then 25), but nothing worked.

here's the log:

```
PS X:\Windows\system32> gem install solargraph
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing solargraph:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
"X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe" -r ./siteconf20191204-11892-whysdy.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:267: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:267: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to X:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby was installed in `Program Files (x86)` which contains a space, which apparently MINGW gems, such as jaro_winkler, don't agree with, so if you encounter this issue change your Ruby install location.